# Autofill formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below formula within Excel which works well. This formula is then dragged down to the bottom of the table.

`=IF(OFFSET(OriginalData!$A$1,MATCH(TempTable!$A2,OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1)=0,"",OFFSET(OriginalData!$A$1,MATCH(TempTable!$A2,OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1))`

I now want to add this to vba and have attempted the following:

```
Private Sub MatchViaEmployeeName()

With Worksheets("TempTable")

Set Usdrws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

.Range(.Cells(1, 1), Usdrws.Offset(, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OFFSET(OriginalData!R1C1,MATCH(TempTable!RC[-1],OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1)=0,"""",OFFSET(OriginalData!R1C1,MATCH(TempTable!RC[-1],OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1))"

End With

End Sub
```

My logic is to select the entire range using the 'Usdrws' variable and then entering the formula.

I'm currently getting a

> run-time error 1004

Comment: Change `""` to `""""` in formula

Comment: Thanks JohnyL, I'm still getting the same error, but that is definitely something that needed fixing

Comment: Also, you use `R1C1` notation, but in your formula there's `$A$1`. Change it to `R1C1`.

Comment: I have also selected the entire column A:A, how do I write that?

Comment: You must use `C1`.

Comment: Excellent thanks JohnyL that's all working now!!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll put my comments into answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formula you need to change:

1. Change `""` to `""""` in formula
2. Change `$A$1` to `R1C1`
3. Change `A:A` to `C1`

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the speech marks in your formula because the whole thing is in speechmarks in VBA

```
 .Range(.Cells(1, 1), Usdrws.Offset(, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(OFFSET(OriginalData!$A$1,MATCH(TempTable!RC[-1],OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1)=0,"""",OFFSET(OriginalData!$A$1,MATCH(TempTable!RC[-1],OriginalData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,1,1))"
```

Comment: I think you meant "double quotes"

Comment: `RC[-1]` is incorrect reference since OP has `$A$1`, i.e. absolute reference.